# Geospatial Social Network Analysis Visualization

Tags: visualization, social-network-analysis, scalability, library

I have a data set that keeps track of who referred someone to a program, and includes the geo coordinates of both parties for each record.

What will be the best way to visualize this kind of data set? This visualization should also be able to use the geo coordinates to place this entities in the map to form clusters, or to superimpose them on a real map.

I am interested in an algorithm and/or a library that will help me do this. Library should be preferably written in Java, Python, Scala, or NodeJS. The record count can be as big as a thousand or hundreds of thousands.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your requirements? are you asking for an algorithm? software tool, library? how big is the data?

Comment: Thanks for the response, i am looking for Algorithm and library but most importantly algorithm, the data is close be hundred of thousands of records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dataset can be viewed as a directed graph. The party's location (latitude and longitude) can be denoted as a node and the directed edge can denote who referred whom. Once the dataset can be viewed as this, the problem boils down to joining co-ordinates with lines.

Answer (score 0):

Just go through Neo4j (graph data base and will be useful for social network analysis) also.. may be helpful

Comment: Neo4j itself does not provide visualization. I don't think this addresses the question, but maybe you can edit it to expand on how you would use this to make a visualization.

Comment: https://gephi.github.io/  It support connecting to neo4j

Comment: @SeanOwen is there a Javascript graph lib that works well with Neo4J that you will recommend. by the way, i have started learning Neo4j

Comment: check this http://neo4j.com/developer/javascript/